# Launch Docker Desktop's Container Via Windows Command-line

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

How do I launch a Docker container, which was created via Docker Desktop, using a Windows command line?

I have containers I created via Docker Desktop. I can launch them via Docker Desktop. I can also launch the hello-world image via a Windows command line. But "docker" commands run via the command line, don't seem to "see" my Docker Desktop containers.

Comment: I suspect Windows can't find my Docker data because I checked "Use the WSL 2 based engine" in Docker Desktop.  Is there a way for Windows' docker.exe to "see" the WSL Docker's containers, or are they hidden from Windows in a .vhdx file?

Comment: [This site](https://dev.to/fanmixco/how-to-run-docker-commands-in-cmdpowershell-from-docker-using-wsl2-5h65) has a work-around. If you put "wsl" in front of your "docker" commands in Windows, you run the WSL2 version of docker.

e.g. If you run `docker images` you list images in the Windows Docker, but if you run `wsl docker images` you list images in the WSL2 Docker.